# Selecting / highlighting text in a JTextArea belonging to a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, joptionpane

My problem is the following:
 In my application the user clicks a button which brings up a dialog box (a custom jOptionPane). This dialog contains a JTextArea in which the user will type a response, which will then be processed by the application, however I would like this JTextArea (which will hold the user's input and currently contains example text like "Write your answer here") to be automatically highlighted.

I can do this normally, by calling requestFocusInWindow() followed by selectAll() on the JTextArea however there seems to be a problem when this is done using a JOptionPane which I'm guessing is to do with the fact that the focus cannot shift to the JTextArea successfully.

I've made a SSCCE to demonstrate this clearly, and hopefully get an answer from one of you guys as to how I can make this possible. Thanks in advance!

**Class 1/2 : Main**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.go();
    }

    private void go() {
        JPanel background = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainPanel = new ExtraPanel();
        ((ExtraPanel) mainPanel).setupPanel();
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Test the jOptionPane");
        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                optionPaneTest();
            }
        });
        background.add(mainPanel);
        background.add(testButton);
        getContentPane().add(background);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void optionPaneTest() {
        JPanel testPanel = new ExtraPanel();
        ((ExtraPanel) testPanel).setupPanel();
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, testPanel,
                "This is a test", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
}
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 **Class 2/2 : ExtraPanel**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ExtraPanel extends JPanel{

    public void setupPanel() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setText("Write your response here");
        textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
        textArea.selectAll();
        add(textArea);
    }

}
```

Comment: The [Dialog focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) article covers just this need..

Comment: I think the problem is that you are focusing and selecting all the text in the `JTextArea` before you add it to the option panel

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  add(textArea); in JOptionPane??? :-)

Comment: I edited my answer to use the AncestorListener. The added bonus for this approach is that the user can immediately start typing in the TextArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want focus in the TextArea so that the user can immediately start typing, you can trigger the selection using the ancestor added event.

```
public void setupPanel() {
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setText("Write your response here");
    textArea.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
        public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) { }
        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) { }
        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == textArea) {
                textArea.selectAll();
                textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }
    });
    add(textArea);
}
```

Comment: Seemed like an interesting idea, and I need to look into ComponentListeners etc but this does not work.

Comment: Thanks very much, your edit works now! Any chance you could explain how the AncestorListener solves this problem?

Comment: `Component.requestFocusInWindow()` docs say, "This component must be displayable, focusable, visible and all of its ancestors (with the exception of the top-level Window) must be visible for the request to be granted." Waiting for `ancestorAdded()` accomplishes that. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow().

Comment: FWIW, I frequently find in Swing that doing things in the right order requires deferring actions to a listener callback, doing them in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, or both (listener callback invokes later).

Comment: Thanks, so far this is the best answer. The getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true) approach means that the text may be highlighted but the JTextArea is not actually focused but just highlighted whereas this approach allows for full selection and focusing.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get more answers to choose from. It's an unlikely puzzle with a rather limited solution set. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
textArea.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true)
```

After `textArea.selectAll();`

Comment: Magic:) in fact when JTextComponent gets focus it turns on selection visibility and turns out when focus is lost. We do the same but directly without focus.

Comment: I see! So would you recommend using this more direct approach as a general rule, and not just now?

Comment: Actually I use the approch where it necessary to show selection ithout focus. E.g. search/replace. User has focused dialog (non modal) above JTextArea but still highlighted selected text.

Comment: 1+, @quantum285, `Thanks this works! ` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: As @StanislavL mentions, this is a very concise solution when you don't need focus in the JTextArea. If you need the selection and focus both, see my answer using the AncestorListener.

Comment: Haven't accepted yet as I don't know whether this will be the best answer, will decide later though. Does anyone have an explanation as to why we can't just select as usual?

Comment: The `selectAll()` actually works in your SSCCE. Shift-tab in the option dialog to see that's the case. It's the call to `requestFocusInWindow()` that fails, so you either have to force the text area to show the selection when not focused like @StanislavL describes, or you have wait to request focus until the component can actually get focus as described in my answer. Each solution works, but for different use cases.